# How to take digits from two different numbers and form a new one

Tags: c#

I have the following problem here:My input is several lines of 2 digit numbers and I need to make a new number using the second digit of the first number and the first of the next one.
Example:

```
int linesOfNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for(int i = 0,i<linesOfNumbers,i++)
{
     int numbers = Conver.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     //that's for reading the input
}
```

I know how to separate the numbers into digits.My question is how to merge them.
For example if your input is 12 and 21 the output should be 22.

Comment: Add some samples you are testing against.

Comment: Sample Input : 12 , 23, 34, 45 the output should be: 22,33,44.

Comment: convert to string first then extract the characters you need. then use `int.Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: `int linesOfNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` won't return an array. So your for-loop won't work. What is your real input? Are you querying each number by a seperated `Console.ReadLine()`? Or is your input in one single line like `12233445` or comma seperated in one line like `12,23,34,45`?

Comment: also, what are your sample inputs? Does `linesOfNumbers` contain the 2 numbers? `firstnumber` and `secondnumber`?

Comment: The first line of the code is how many 2 digit numbers I'll be given and then the actual numbers.For example N(linesOfNumbers) = 4 , numbers = 12,23,34,45 each on a new line

Comment: Ok, thank you. Your are right. That should work. I have updated my answer (scroll down). Hopefully that works.

Comment: @Georgi - It sounds like you are learning, which is great.  Do yourself a favor and forget the `Convert` class exists.  You don't need it.  It's a crutch.  Learn about parsing, formatting, casting, etc.  In other words `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [oRole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46503489/1195056), but I think they're missing a couple things with the example input that you provided in your comment. I'll also point out some of the errors in the code that you have.

First off, if you're only given the input `12,23,34,45`, then you don't need to call `Console.ReadLine` within your `for` loop. You've already gotten the input, you don't need to get any more (from what you've described).

Secondly, unless you're doing mathematical operations, there is no need to store numerical data as `int`s, keep it as a `string`, especially in this case. (What I mean is that you don't store Zip Codes in a database as a number, you store it as a string.)

Now, onto the code. You had the right way to get your data:

```
var listOfNumbers = Console.ReadLine();
```

At that point, `listOfNumbers` is equal to `"12,23,34,45"`. If you iterate on that variable as a string, you'll be taking each individual character, including the commas. To get each of the numbers to operate on, you'll need to use [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var numbers = listOfNumbers.Split(',');
```

This turns that list into four different two character numbers (in string form). Now, you can iterate over them, but you don't need to worry about converting them to numbers as you're operating on the characters in each string. Also, you'll need a results collection to put everything into.

```
var results = new List<string>();

// Instead of the regular "i < numbers.Length", we want to skip the last.
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
{
    var first = numbers[i];
    var second = numbers[i + 1]; // This is why we skip the last.

    results.Add(first[1] + second[0]);
}
```

Now your `results` is a collection of the numbers `"22"`, `"33"`, and `"44"`. To get those back into a single string, you can use the helper method [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results));
```

Comment: Let me know if your `12,23,34,45` are not coming in with a single `Console.ReadLine`, and I can adjust for that.

Comment: Yea.The first line of the input is how many numbers i'll be given, The next N lines are the actual input, but despite that your answer is what i was looking for :)

Comment: Thanks @krillgar for pointing that out. I like your answer too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code snippet will help you combining your numbers. The modulo operator (%) means: 53 / 10 = 5 Rest **3**

This example shows the computation of the numbers 34 and 12

```
int firstNumber = 34 - (34 % 10) // firstNumber = 30
int secondNumber = 12 % 10; // secondNumber = 2
int combined = firstNumber + secondNumber; // combined = 32
```

**EDIT (added reading and ouput code)**:

```
boolean reading = true;
List<int> numbers = new ArrayList();
while(reading)
{
    try
    {
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (number > 9 && number < 100) numbers.Add(number);
        else reading = false; // leave reading process if no 2-digit-number
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // leave reading process by typing a character instead of a number;
        reading = false;
    }
}

if (numbers.Count() > 1)
{
    List<int> combined = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.Count(); i++)
    {
        combined.Add((numbers[i-1] % 10) + (numbers[i] - (numbers[i] % 10)));
    }

    //Logging output:
    foreach (int combination in combined) Console.WriteLine(combination);
}
```

Comment: It'd be good to understand where the magic numbers `34` and `12` come from (other than they were provided in the question) to help make this more readable. I also don't understand why you're doing `-=` when initializing `firstNumber`.

Comment: I took other numbers than the two of the question because 12 and 21 were not practical because one number is a flipped version of the other. So I replaced 21 with 34. And your second argument... damn. You are right. I will fix this.

Comment: Understandable. With my first point, I meant you should demonstrate what you did to get the numbers into the `34` and `12`.

Comment: Ok @krillgar. I have edited my answer. Now it offers a reading-process, too.

Comment: Thanks! With this being a beginner question, it's good to not leave anything unexplained. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the string-method `.Substring(..)` to achieve what you want.

If you want to keep int-conversion in combination with user input, you could do:

```
int numA = 23;
int numB = 34;
int resultAB = Convert.ToInt16(numA.ToString().Substring(1, 1) + numB.ToString().Substring(0, 1));
```

Another option would be to take the users input as string values and to convert them afterwards like that:

```
string numC = "12";
string numD = "21";
int resultCD = Convert.ToInt16(numC.Substring(1, 1) + numD.Substring(0, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, if you already have both numbers, and they are always valid two digit integers, following code should work for you.

```
var num1 = 12;
var num2 = 22;
var result = (num2 / 10)*10 + (num1 % 10);
```

`num2/10` returns the first digit of second number, and `num1 % 10` returns the second digit of the first number.

Comment: this is assuming all are 2-digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The % and / signs are your savior.

If you want the 'ones' digit of a number (lets call it X), simply do X%10 - the remainder will be whatever number is in the 'ones' digit. (23%10=3)

If, instead, the number is two digits and you want the 'tens' digit, divide it by ten. (19/10=1).

To merge them, multiply the number you want to be in the 'tens' digit by ten, and add the other number to it (2*10+2=22)

Comment: That's nice but how do i do it for 2 separate instances of the loop. For example they type in first 34 i should that 4 and then its typed in 56 and I must take 5

Comment: create three integers outside of the loop - first,second,result. inside the loop: do console.readline (with parsing) for the first number, do result=first%10, do console.readline() on the second number, and do result+=second. It works with any pair of two digit numbers you enter

Answer (score -1):

There are other solutions like substring, etc and many one have already given it above. I am giving the solution VIA LINQ, note that this isn't efficient and it's recommended only for learning purpose here

```
 int numA = 12;
 int numB = 21 ;

 string secondPartofNumA = numA.ToString().Select(q => new string(q,1)).ToArray()[1]; // first digit
 string firstPartofNumB = numB.ToString().Select(q => new string(q,1)).ToArray()[0]; // second digit

 string resultAsString = secondPartofNumA + firstPartofNumB;
 int resultAsInt = Convert.ToInt32(resultAsString);

 Console.WriteLine(resultAsString);
 Console.WriteLine(resultAsInt);
```

Comment: That is not at all a good use for LINQ. This is one of the rare times when LINQ is less readable. Also the performance of this is going to be dreadful. While a new student should definitely be aware of when and how to use LINQ, they should also be aware of when to not use it.

Comment: There were some answers already added using substring and other methods, so to present one more way I have added that. I agree LINQ might appear to be complicated for beginner but it might be helpful for some other readers. So just to add variety to the answer and as the answer was already added, I presented it. I hope you remove downvote as it hurts :(